# policy.addAwsAccountPrincipal() throwing MalformedPolicyDocument error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a role using CDK and here's requirements 
1. access to api gateway(GET,DELETE,PUT,POST)
2. has a trust relationship with an aws account, "1234567"

Here's my CDK typescript code:

```
const role = new iam.Role(this, 'IMAAPIGatewayAccessRole', {
    roleName: 'IMAAPIGatewayAccessRole',
    assumedBy: new iam.AnyPrincipal(),

});

role.addToPolicy(new PolicyStatement(iam.PolicyStatementEffect.Allow)
    .addAwsAccountPrincipal('1234567') 
    .addActions(
        "apigateway:GET",
        "apigateway:POST",
        "apigateway:PUT",
        "apigateway:DELETE"
    )
    .addAllResources()
);
```

But I am having MalformedPolicyDocument error
But I am not getting it without addAwsAccountPrincipal().

```
AssumeRolepolicy contained an invalid principal: "STAR":"*". (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: cb4073ee-aa5d-11e9-b299-c7ffa44eb0ca)
        new Role (/Users//workspace/cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-iam/lib/role.ts:200:18)
        \_ new Ims (/Users//workspace/cdk/bin/cdk.ts:25:22)
        \_ Object.<anonymous> (/Users//workspace/cdk/bin/cdk.ts:285:1)
        \_ Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
        \_ Module.m._compile (/Users//workspace/cdk/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
        \_ Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
        \_ Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/Users//workspace/cdk/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
        \_ Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
        \_ Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
        \_ Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
        \_ Object.<anonymous> (/Users//workspace/cdk/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:154:12)
        \_ Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
        \_ Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
        \_ Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
        \_ Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
        \_ Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10)
        \_ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/libnpx/index.js:268:14
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: "assumedBy: new iam.AccountPrincipal(stageAccountId)" also throwing the error

Answer (score 2):

addAwsAccountPrincipal('1234567') doesn't actually work for me. Maybe it's a bug.

Instead, below worked for me.

```
const allowedAccountPrincipals = subscriberAccountIds.map(id => new AccountPrincipal(id));
        const [firstPrincipal, ...additionalAllowedPrincipal] = allowedAccountPrincipals;
        const allowedPrincipals = new CompositePrincipal(firstPrincipal, ...additionalAllowedPrincipal);

        const role = new iam.Role(this, 'IMAAPIGatewayAccessRole', {
            roleName: 'IMAAPIGatewayAccessRole',
            assumedBy: allowedPrincipals,
        });
```